Fundamental Question on Noise Figure
I'm doing a course on noise and came across Noise Figure. It is said that noise figure for a circuit can never be less than 1.
But we typically say we remove noise by using filters.
So if the output has less noise, won't that mean a higher SNR, and then by definition, a noise figure of less than 1 for such filters?

As Barry said "noise figure is a measure of how much noise a circuit has added to its input" and is one of the key FOM when studying the minimum detectable SNR of a signal. Because noise figure deals with SNR it is typically only discussed in relation to the passband of the signal (see note 1) as we want to see how the signal level will compare to the noise level in the passband. We don't worry about signals outside the passband because they don't interfere with our signal to the same extent (see note 2). In summary when you talk about noise figure the noise and the signal are assumed to be in the same band/frequency range. So while the noise in the stopband of a filter might attenuated, so to would any signal in that stop band be attenuated leading to an increase in the noise figure (see note 3).
It is important though to note that the total noise power is given by kTB where k, is the Boltzmann constant, T is the temperature in kelvin, and B is the bandwidth. This implies that when you filter the signal you will decrease the bandwidth and therefore decrease the total noise power (boosting the SNR), but that is not what noise figure measures. Instead noise figure measures from the input of your receiver to the output how much additional noise is added to (kT)

There are cases where we might look outside the passband when calculating SNR. Especially in the case of mixers which might mix noise from both the upper and lower side bands together (doubling the noise)
This of course assumes again no mixers and that we sample the signal at a high enough frequency to avoid aliasing
Typically for passive components like filters the noise figure is considered to be the insertion loss of the filter at the frequency of interest


Thank you very much. This clears it up for me. My course does mention spot noise when calculating noise power so I should have known it's only the pass band noise.

Noise Figure is a measure of how much noise a circuit has added to its input. It is independent of the noise that is already in the input signal. An ideal circuit would contribute no additional noise and thus have a noise figure of 1. Since no circuit is noise free, the noise figure is always greater than 1.
